# add mediaplayer function without oncreate

Tags: java, android

I am making a camera application but I want to add music to this activity and I have a fragment for example:

`public class Camera extends Fragment`

and this my error in photo:

[image]

but this code out on Create because I have fragment activity and this full code:

```
    implements View.OnClickListener, FragmentCompat.OnRequestPermissionsResultCallback {
private static final int SENSOR_ORIENTATION_DEFAULT_DEGREES = 90;
private static final int SENSOR_ORIENTATION_INVERSE_DEGREES = 270;
private static final SparseIntArray DEFAULT_ORIENTATIONS = new SparseIntArray();
private static final SparseIntArray INVERSE_ORIENTATIONS = new SparseIntArray();

private static final String TAG = "Camera2VideoFragment";
private static final int REQUEST_VIDEO_PERMISSIONS = 1;
private static final String FRAGMENT_DIALOG = "dialog";

private static final String[] VIDEO_PERMISSIONS = {
        Manifest.permission.CAMERA,
        Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO,
};

static {
    DEFAULT_ORIENTATIONS.append(Surface.ROTATION_0, 90);
    DEFAULT_ORIENTATIONS.append(Surface.ROTATION_90, 0);
    DEFAULT_ORIENTATIONS.append(Surface.ROTATION_180, 270);
    DEFAULT_ORIENTATIONS.append(Surface.ROTATION_270, 180);
}
MediaPlayer mediaPlayer=MediaPlayer.create(Camera2VideoFragment.this,R.raw.adn);


static {
    INVERSE_ORIENTATIONS.append(Surface.ROTATION_0, 270);
    INVERSE_ORIENTATIONS.append(Surface.ROTATION_90, 180);
    INVERSE_ORIENTATIONS.append(Surface.ROTATION_180, 90);
    INVERSE_ORIENTATIONS.append(Surface.ROTATION_270, 0);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that you are passing a `Fragment` where it should be a `Context`.
Try changing for `Camera2VideoFragment.this.getContext()`.